# MySQL - How to Avoid Query Locking

Tags: mysql, locking

We use InnoDB engine for our mysql database but since the data set is huge we aggregate data in flat myisam table. We have to use myisam because we also utilizing full-text search.

Generally queries against flat table as much faster, but the problem is that we now have to run update script which locks all search queries for long....

I wonder if there is a better way maintaining search table or how to run update script without locking other search queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can afford the extra space, the simplest option would to be to create the new table under the separate name and then use rename to swap in the new table. Then you can drop the old table.

Alternatively, you might consider something like [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) which will index your table for you and provides search APIs for most popular languages.

Answer (score 0):

While I think MySQL is great, the full text search functionality is (IMHO) just a bad idea.

The only places I have seen it applied are for implementing user-driven keyword searching functionality or for getting around a really badly designed and not-normalised schemas.

It does not allow for the level of control needed for the kind of search functionality provided by yahoo, google et al. OTOH implementing a structure to support that control/flexibility is trivial.

As for a bolt on fix for mistakes made elsewhere.....really you should fix the mistake.

But leaving that aside for the time being....

You can't sensibly avoid locking the table for most of the update on a MyISAM engine. However you can perform the update in chunks to reduce the impact on other queries requiring faster access to the data.

However if you're only updating a small portion of the rows in the table, and the time taken is mainly in finding the rows using non/poorly indexed columns, then you might want to SELECT the primary keys of the table into a temporary table then use that to drive the update.